# ArrayList getting randomly updated

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this simple program to compute all the subsets of a given set.

The algorithm, I believe is correct.
However in part:

```
while (included.size()>0){
    ArrayList<Integer> temp =included.remove(0);
    temp.add(first_element);
    output.add(temp);
}
```

the statement `temp.add(first_element)` is unnecessarily updating not_included.
Please help me understand why.

```
public class Recursion {

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getSubsets (ArrayList<Integer> input_set){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> output=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        if (input_set.isEmpty()){
            ArrayList<Integer> this_subset=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            output.add(this_subset);
        }      
        else if (input_set.size()==1){
            ArrayList<Integer> empty_subset=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            output.add(input_set);
            output.add(empty_subset);
        }
        else{
            int first_element=input_set.remove(0);
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> included = getSubsets(input_set);
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> not_included = getSubsets(input_set);

            while (included.size()>0){
                ArrayList<Integer> temp =included.remove(0);
                temp.add(first_element);
                output.add(temp);
            }
            while (not_included.size()>0){
                output.add(not_included.remove(0));
            }
        }
        return output;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> test= new ArrayList<Integer> ();
        test.add(2);
        test.add(1);
        System.out.print(getSubsets(test));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> not_included = getSubsets(input_set.clone());
```

This might still not work though since your generic type of the array list is also an array list. Search for "deep copying" to find a 100% working solution.

getSubSet only returns a pointer to the same list since the parameter is the same, that's why included and not_included are the same lists.

Comment: is it because the function getSubsets is static?

Comment: @ManasPaldhe That has absolutely nothing to do with it. You should take a look how objects are referenced in Java since there are no (direct) pointers.